# Dynamically named temp table returns "invalid object name" when referenced in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

When I run the following code, I get an "invalid object name" error, any idea why?

I need to create a dynamically named temp table to be used in a stored procedure.

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @SessionID NVARCHAR(50)
 SET @SessionID = 'tmp5l7g9q3l1h1n5s4k9k7e'
 ;
 SET        
 @SQL = N'      CREATE TABLE #' + @SessionID + ' ' +
         N'     (' +
    N'      CustomerNo NVARCHAR(5), ' +
    N'      Product NVARCHAR(3), ' + 
    N'      Gross DECIMAL(18,8) ' +
    N'      )'
 ;
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
 ;
 SET        
 @SQL = N'      SELECT * FROM #' + @SessionID
 ;
 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need to so this, #temp tables are automatically (behind the scenes) already names uniquely between database sessions??

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that!  So if I just call it something like #SumTable, I won't run into a problem with more than one person running the procedure at the same time creating the same temp table?

Comment: Create some #temp then look at the actual names in TempDB.  You will see that it appends to the name.

Comment: @tom, no you won't. Temp table that being with # are local in scope and will not in any way clofklict with other users in adiffernt scope. Temp tables begining with ## are gloabal and can be seen and used by other users.

Comment: @Tom, the database will keep each #temp table separate for each session, see my answer below.  If you want a temp table to be seen across different processes use two `#` like: ##GlobalTempTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong!

Try:

```
exec(@SQL)
```

instead of:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

---

To use `sp_executesql` the variable must be inside `@SessionID` the quotes and it must be provided has input parameter. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for a full example!

---

You've to be aware that Dynamic SQL is a good port for SQL injections!

Comment: Yeah thanks, I generate that SessionID so injection shouldn't be an issue.  As far as the above syntax, I can use that to dynamically refer to column and table names without error, why not creating a temporary table?

Comment: @af, `Have you tried to create the temp table with that name without using dynamic sql? To check if it's possible.. ` **what? there is no "if it's possible"**.  It will manage the names for you period, that is how it is documented and that is how it works.

Answer (score 3):

**WHY MESS WITH THE NAMES?** Let SQL Server will manage this for you:

[Temporary Tables in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/)

from the above link:

> If the same routine is executed simultaneously by several processes,
>   the Database Engine needs to be able to distinguish between the
>   identically-named local temporary tables created by the different
>   processes. It does this by adding a numeric string to each local
>   temporary table name left-padded by underscore characters. Although
>   you specify the short name such as #MyTempTable, what is actually
>   stored in TempDB is made up of the table name specified in the CREATE
>   TABLE statement and the suffix. Because of this suffix, local
>   temporary table names must be 116 characters or less.
>
> If you’re interested in seeing what is going on, you can view the
>   tables in TempDB just the same way you would any other table. You can
>   even use sp_help work on temporary tables only if you invoke them from
>   TempDB.

```
USE TempDB
go
execute sp_Help #mytemp
```

> or you can find them in the system views of TempDB without swithching
>   databases.

```
SELECT name, create_date FROM TempDB.sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '#%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax works

```
CREATE TABLE #SessionID (CustomerNo NVARCHAR(5),  Product NVARCHAR(3),  Gross DECIMAL(18,8));
Select COUNT(*) from #SessionID;
Drop Table #SessionID;
```